# Get Javascript object array from table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am likely new at javascript, i want to extract data from table in json object format 
I have a table look like this

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="active">Bolumn</th>
<th class="active">Column</th>
<th class="active">Dolumn</th>
<th>Molumn</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="active">Bolumn Data</td>
<td class="active">Column Data</td>
<td class="active">Dolumn Data</td>
<td>Molumn Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="active">Bolumn Data 1</td>
<td class="active">Column Data 1</td>
<td class="active">Dolumn Data 1</td>
 <td>Molumn Data 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="active">Bolumn Data 2</td>
<td class="active">Column Data 2</td>
<td class="active">Dolumn Data 2</td>
<td>Molumn Data 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In table some of have active class and i want only this active class data

So I want json formated look like this and i want in jquery method

```
[{"Bolumn":"Bolumn Data","Column":"Column Data","Dolumn":"Dolumn Data"},
{"Bolumn":"Bolumn Data 1","Column":"Column Data 1","Dolumn":"Dolumn Data 1"},
{"Bolumn":"Bolumn Data 2","Column":"Column Data 2","Dolumn":"Dolumn Data 2"}]
```

Thanks in Advance

Updated:
I've tried like this code but i don't how to achieve this

```
var array = [];
$('tr').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            array.push($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you find that your implied question is *"Can someone please do this for me?"*, then it's likely not yet at a stage where it should be asked on StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to familiarize with [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make an attempt before requesting help.

Comment: Good or not, you need to make an effort of your own, so provide what you have so far using jQuery

Comment: I've tried lot way but success @TylerRoper

Comment: Show us what looks like your best try in a [mcve] - click the `<>` - you need to run over `$("th.active")` and `$("td.active")`

Comment: Thanks for adding the code to your answer. It makes it a lot easier to provide a useable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite close to working. It needs a few things however to get your desired results. First, since you want objects, you need the keys, which are found in the header. You can make an array of these the same way you are doing for your data:

```
var headers = []
$('tr th').each(function (i) {
    headers.push($(this).text())
})
```

Now you can reference the headers by index in your loop and assign values to the keys as you go:

```js
// find headers
var headers = []
$('tr th').each(function(i) {
  headers.push($(this).text())
})
// result array
var array = [];
$('tr').each(function(i) {
  // declare object variable but dont set it's value
  // unless there are objects to find
  var rowObj
  $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
    if (!rowObj) rowObj = {}
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      // use the header we found earlier
      rowObj[headers[i]] = $(this).text()
    }
  });
  // if we found active objects, rowObje will be defined
  if (rowObj) array.push(rowObj)
});
console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="active">Bolumn</th>
      <th class="active">Column</th>
      <th class="active">Dolumn</th>
      <th>Molumn</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data</td>
      <td>Molumn Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data 1</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data 1</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data 1</td>
      <td>Molumn Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data 2</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data 2</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data 2</td>
      <td>Molumn Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a jQuery solution, here is mine with vanilla js and ES6 that utilizes `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Learning those would be useful in the future and will help you write more declarative code.

```js
// 1) extract headers and rows in separate arrays with 
//    respective `isActive` flag for each item in both

var [headers, ...rows] = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')].map(
  tr =>  [...tr.querySelectorAll('*')].map(n => ({
  name: n.innerText,
  isActive: n.classList.contains('active')
})));

// 2) iterate over the `rows` and dynamically aggregate the output object 
//    by matching headers and rows based on their indexes:

var result = rows.map(row => {
  return headers.reduce((obj, h, j) => {
    if (h.isActive && row[j].isActive) {
      obj[h.name] = row[j].name;
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="active">Bolumn</th>
      <th class="active">Column</th>
      <th class="active">Dolumn</th>
      <th>Molumn</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data</td>
      <td>Molumn Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data 1</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data 1</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data 1</td>
      <td>Molumn Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">Bolumn Data 2</td>
      <td class="active">Column Data 2</td>
      <td class="active">Dolumn Data 2</td>
      <td>Molumn Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would be more specific: `...tr.querySelectorAll('td, th')`